# Can set-theoretic forcing exist without law of excluded middle?

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

Of course the law of excluded middle is accepted by almost every mathematician except a few constructivists, but then I was wondering if set-theoretic forcing can exist without law of excluded middle. Of course some may say that the real question must be what will happen set theories (eg. ZF) without excluded middle, but then I will stick with my question.

Comment: Forcing in an intuitionistic context is studied via algebraic set theory. There are works to generalize the idea of forcing to toposes and whatnot. But I don't really know much about that.

Comment: If nothing else, you can first construct a theory by adding $P$ whenever $\neg \neg P$ is a theorem: this will be consistent (assuming the original is), and will satisfy the law of the excluded middle, and then you can continue on in terms of that. Assuming, of course, you are in a system where $\neg P \equiv \neg \neg \neg P$ (e.g. intuitionistic logic)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Consider Intuitionistic Zermelo set theory (IZ) and Intuitionistic Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory (IZF) as presented in chapter 8 of Bell's "Set Theory:  Boolean-valued models and Independence Proofs", third edition.  Forcing in these set theories would use Heyting-algebra-valued models as classical ZF would use Boolean-valued models (pp. 165-166).  Bell shows that the Law of Excluded Middle (LEM) holds in a Heyting-algebra-valued model if and only if the Heyting algebra in question is a boolean algebra.  Since the Axiom of Choice implies LEM, the Axiom of choice does not hold in any Heyting-algebra-valued model for which the Heyting algebra in question is not a boolean algebra (this last sentence is a paraphrase of a statement of Bell's found on pg. 166 of his book).